# JQGrid not closing dropdown after cancel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid selector, where the key is a dropdown I've populated via JSON.

Works great, and when the user selects from the dropdown, the dropdown collapses, all is good.

What I've noticed, is that when the dropdown is showing and the user clicks the cancel button on the JQGrid, the dropdown still shows, even though the entire JQGrid is closed!

The settings I have are:

```
   jQuery("#providerItemProperties").jqGrid('navGrid', '#propertiesItemPager', {
      del : true,
      add : true,
      edit : true,
      search : false
   }, {
      closeAfterEdit : true
   }, {
      closeOnEscape: true
   }, {
      closeAfterAdd : true
   });
```

It's almost as if JQGrid is missing a closeAfterCancel option, but I would assume that is implied.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in my test examples. Probably you use some non-standard control as the dropdown?

Comment: Hi Oleg, wrote our own and merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out a hacky way to accomplish this.

I added the following:

```
onClose = function() {
   $(".jqComboList").hide();
```

}

to my jqGrid, now when they exit, it looks for that list and if it exists, hides it.  Wish there was a better way, but it works I guess. :)